# Find and delete files that contain same string in filename in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, find, delete-file

I want to delete all files from a folder that contain a not unique numerical string in the filename using linux terminal. E.g.:

```
werrt-110009.jpg => delete
asfff-110009.JPG => delete
asffa-123489.jpg => maintain
asffa-111122.JPG => maintain
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using /bin/bash.

Comment: I've written a completely new answer, please check if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only now understand your question, I think. You want to remove all files that contain a numeric value that is not unique (in a particular folder). If a filename contains a value that is also found in another filename, you want to remove both files, right?

This is how I would do that (it may not be the fastest way):

```sh
# put all files in your folder in a list
# for array=(*) to work make sure you have enabled nullglob: shopt -s nullglob
array=(*)
delete=()

for elem in "${array[@]}"; do
    # for each elem in your list extract the number
    num_regex='([0-9]+)\.'
    [[ "$elem" =~ $num_regex ]]
    num="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # use the extracted number to check if it is unique
    dup_regex="[^0-9]($num)\..+?(\1)"
    # if it is not unique, put the file in the files-to-delete list
    if [[ "${array[@]}" =~ $dup_regex ]]; then
        delete+=("$elem")
    fi
done

# delete all found duplicates
for elem in "${delete[@]}"; do
    rm "$elem"
done
```

In your example, `array` would be:

```
array=(werrt-110009.jpg asfff-110009.JPG asffa-123489.jpg asffa-111122.JPG)
```

And the result in `delete` would be:

```
delete=(werrt-110009.jpg asfff-110009.JPG)
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: This works on the local drive as required, for a mounted drive on a third party server it is too slow. On the server I use:
<?php
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../to/folder')) as $filename){
$arr[] = substr("$filename", -10, 6); 
}
$dubs = array_unique(array_diff_assoc( $arr, array_unique( $arr ) ) );
foreach ($dubs as &$rem){
array_map('unlink', glob($path . "/*" . $rem . ".jpg"));
}
?>
instead: Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the linux find command along with the -regex parameter and the -delete parameter
to do it in one command

Answer (score 0):

Use "rm" command to delete all matching string files in directory

```
cd <path-to-directory>/ && rm *110009*
```

This command helps to delete all files with matching string and it doesn't depend on the position of string in file name.

I was mentioned rm command option as another option to delete files with matching string.

Below is the complete script to achieve your requirement,

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

#provide the destination fodler path
DEST_FOLDER_PATH="$1"

TEMP_BUILD_DIR="/tmp/$( date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)_clenup_duplicate_files"
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
clean_up()
{
    if [ -d $TEMP_BUILD_DIR ]; then
        rm -rf $TEMP_BUILD_DIR
    fi
}
trap clean_up EXIT

[ ! -d $TEMP_BUILD_DIR ] && mkdir -p $TEMP_BUILD_DIR
TEMP_FILES_LIST_FILE="$TEMP_BUILD_DIR/folder_file_names.txt"
echo "$(ls $DEST_FOLDER_PATH)" > $TEMP_FILES_LIST_FILE
while read filename
do
    #check files with number pattern
    if [[ "$filename" =~ '([0-9]+)\.' ]]; then
        #fetch the number to find files with similar number
        matching_string="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

        # use the extracted number to check if it is unique
        #find the files count with matching_string
        if [ $(ls -1 $DEST_FOLDER_PATH/*$matching_string* | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
            rm $DEST_FOLDER_PATH/*$matching_string*
        fi
    fi
    #reload remaining files in folder (this optimizes the loop and speeds up the operation
    #(this helps lot when folder contains more files))
    echo "$(ls $DEST_FOLDER_PATH)" > $TEMP_FILES_LIST_FILE
done < $TEMP_FILES_LIST_FILE

exit 0
```

How to execute this script,

1. Save this script into file as
   path-to-script/delete_duplicate_files.sh (you can rename whatever
   you want)
2. Make script executable

   chmod +x {path-to-script}/delete_duplicate_files.sh
3. Execute script by providing directory path where duplicate
   files(files with matching number pattern) needs to be deleted

   {path-to-script}/delete_duplicate_files.sh "{path-to-directory}"

Comment: Thank you, but this would require that I know the numbers that are double and manual input, but the folder has over 10k files. I thought that I might have to group the files by their numerical string and then delete where the group count is >1.

Comment: Thank you for the well elaborated script. Unfortunately I get following error: {path-to-script}/delete_duplicate_files.sh: 22: {path-to-script}/delete_duplicate_files.sh: [[: not found .

Comment: path-to-script --> is directory path where you want to keep script. for example if you want keep this script in your home folder then save the script at $HOME/delete_duplicate_files.sh. and then chmod +x $HOME/delete_duplicate_files.sh.  After this, path-to-directory -> is directory path where your files are located say $HOME/images, then you need to run script as $HOME/delete_duplicate_files.sh "$HOME/images"

Comment: If problem is not related to what I mentioned above then could you provide complete terminal commands you are using to run this script.